# Writing a macro for Excel that dynamically removes and reorganizing remaining columns from a table of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a system that I pull data from monthly for a variety of accounts and the system is regularly used by others and that changes the order of the columns, adds and subtracts columns based on various needs, and I'm looking for a way to take that dynamic report once exported, paste into one sheet of a workbook in excel, on another, allow my team to paste in the row of columns they need for their specific uses, in the order they need, then run the macro and have it remove all unnecessary columns, and reorganize the columns into the required order onto a new workbook.

I have a working system for the removal of unnecessary systems, BUT it's not dynamic, as each kept column is set in the macro. (Original macro found here [Deleting all columns except columns with certain headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597841/deleting-all-columns-except-columns-with-certain-headings), and adjusted accordingly to my needs to create the new file and clear the old.)

```
    Sub deleteIrrelevantColumns()
    Dim keepColumn As Boolean
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String
    currentColumn = 1
    While currentColumn <= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").UsedRange.Columns.Count
        columnHeading = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value
        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        keepColumn = False
            If columnHeading = "Account Number" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "Invoiced" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "Create Date" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "Customer Reference" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "Origin Country" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "Destination Country" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "DestinationLocationCode" Then keepColumn = True
            If columnHeading = "Weight" Then keepColumn = True



        If keepColumn Then
        'IF YES THEN SKIP TO THE NEXT COLUMN,
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
        Else
        'IF NO DELETE THE COLUMN
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Columns(currentColumn).Delete
        End If
        'LASTLY AN ESCAPE IN CASE THE SHEET HAS NO COLUMNS LEFT
        If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").UsedRange.Address = "$A$1") And (ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Text = "") Then Exit Sub
    
    Wend
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Cells.Clear
End Sub
```

I have also found [Reordering Multiple Columns in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702934/reordering-multiple-columns-in-excel-vba) which looks like I can have my team paste their list of needed columns in the appropriate order into a static place on the excel file, and have it pull the range of cells into the array, but I'm not sure how to combine these two together, to make that work together. Ideally, I'd like to be able to get a drop down on one sheet for them to just select the account they would like, and the system automatically fills in all of the columns in the order they need.

I'm trying to learn as much of all of this as I can, but I'm struggling with understanding how all of the VBA meshes together.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have duplicate headers, you probably want to put your data and  user settings into [tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) ([listobject Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject))

This allows you to reference [columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.listcolumns) by name, and you could easily create an In-Cell Dropdown of possible columns for your users through validation via headerRowRange or [structured references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

```
Dim wrksht As Worksheet 
Dim oListCol As ListColumn 

Set wrksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA") 
Set oListCol = wrksht.ListObjects([Your Table Name Here]).ListColumns("Weight")
```